# $AM=I$, where $M$ is a rectangular matrix with full column rank, prove that $A=M^+$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$AM=I$, where $M$ is a rectangular matrix with full column rank, then $A=M^+ $(Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse)?

Comment: What is $M^{+}$? The [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)?

Comment: @EuYu: yes, MP pseudoinverse

Comment: If that's the case, then the statement in your question is incorrect. The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is uniquely defined, whereas $A$ is just a left-inverse of $M$. One-sided inverses of matrices are not unique; there are multiple matrices which can play the role of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that all but one of the defining properties of the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse are satisfied. The missing one is
$$
(MA)^H = MA.
$$
As EuYu pointed out, $A$ is just a left-inverse.

A counter-example would be:
$$
M = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}.
$$
Then all matrices of type 
$$
A = \pmatrix{ 1 & a}
$$ 
satisfy your assumptions, but only for $a=0$ the product $MA$ is Hermitian, thus
$$
M^+ = \pmatrix{ 1 & 0}.
$$